# Not understanding the condition

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

I'm having problem with the condition that is in the for loop, I don't understand it, I know what it does, but I can't understand the logic of the code condition, can someone please explain it to me the logic of the condition:

`if(smallWord == null || bigWord.compareTo(smallWord)<0)`

```
/*2.   Enter the Exercise2 class that performs this function:
                1. Instructs the user to type a number [at least four (4): to use while loop] which indicates how many 
    words / sentences will be typed, and using for loop to ask the user to type those words / sentences.
                2. Find and display on the console which word / sentence is the smallest (comes first alphabetically). */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Type a number greater than 4");
       int size = scan.nextInt();

       while (size < 4) {
           System.out.println("Type a number greater than 4");
           size = scan.nextInt();
       }

       scan.nextLine();
       String smallWord = null;
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           System.out.println("Shtypni fjaline e " + (i + 1) + ": ");
           String bigWord = scan.next();
           if (smallWord == null || bigWord.compareTo(smallWord) < 0) {
               smallWord = bigWord;
           }
       }
       System.out.println("The smallest word/sentence alphabetically is: " + smallWord);
  }
}
```

Comment: `smallWord == null` makes sure the conditional is true the first time through the loop. See also: [`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String))

Comment: It might make sense to “play computer” with pen/paper through the code and that loop (a or add logging before and inside the loop, or step through with a debugger).

Answer (score 0):

The condition ensures that `bigWord` will be assigned to `smallWord` if:

**smallWord == null**

Or

**bigWord is 'lesser' than smallWord** (because `compareTo()` returns a value less than 0 if the string is lexicographically less than the argument)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the for loop as a whole is to find the word that is lexicographically the smallest.
The way this is done is to compare each new word (bigWord) to the smallest one found so far (smallWord).

So the if test says 'if either no smallest word has been found so far, or this new word is smaller than the one found so far, then this new word is the smallest one we have right now'.